# Mapping variables in two data frames using a third data frame

Tags: performance, r

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2` of identical structure. The first three columns, `id`, `form`, and `instance` identify the participant and form(s). The remaining variable columns, `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, contain analytic data and are largely identical except for a few slight discrepancies.

I have a third data frame, `map` that identifies the id, form(s), and variables that have discrepancies, but does not contain the values of these discrepancies. I would like to use the `map` data to create a final data frame, `df.final` that appends two columns and places the discrepant values from `df1` and `df2`.

Below I am providing sample data as well as a clunky-but-working `for` loop that creates the desired `df.final`. It is very slow (takes several hours to run on the full dataset) - so slow in fact it is functionally unusable (this ideally needs to be updated in near real time). I am hoping someone better at coding than me can provide alternative, faster solutions.

(Note that given the simplicity of the example data, there are alternate ways to compare `df1` and `df2`, but assume these don't work and using `map` is the only option.)

```
# Example data, df1
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(sprintf("K00%s", 0:9), each = 3),
                  form = rep(c("A","B", "B"), times = 10),
                  instance = rep(c("None", "1", "2"), times = 10),
                  var1 = sample(LETTERS, 30, replace = TRUE),
                  var2 = rnbinom(30, mu = 1, size = 0.02),
                  var3 = sample(c("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"), 30, replace = TRUE))

# Sample data df2, same as df1 but with slight discrepancies
df2 <- df1
df2[15, 4] <- "A"
df2[c(4, 6, 8), 5] <- c(11,15,16)
df2[27:28, 6] <- "Bannanas"

# Example "Map" that only indicates what ID, form, instance, and variable is discrepant
map <- data.frame(id = c("K004", "K001", "K001", "K002", "K008", "K009"),
                  form = c("B","A", "B", "B", "B", "A"),
                  instance = c("2", "None", "2", "1", "2", "None"),
                  variable = c("var1", rep("var2", 3), "var3", "var3"))

# id form instance variable
# 1 K004    B        2     var1
# 2 K001    A     None     var2
# 3 K001    B        2     var2
# 4 K002    B        1     var2
# 5 K008    B        2     var3
# 6 K009    A     None     var3

## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
# Currently working for-loop, but VERY slow in full data
## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

df.final <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 6))

for (i in 1:nrow(map)){
  keepcols <- c("id", "form","instance", map[i,4])
  m1 <- merge(map[i,], df1[ , keepcols], by = keepcols[-4])
  m2 <- merge(m1, df2[, keepcols], by = keepcols[-4])
  df.final[i,] <- m2
}
names(df.final) <- c(names(map), "df1_entry","df2_entry")
df.final

#   id     form instance variable      df1_entry df2_entry
# 1 K004    B        2     var1         P         A
# 2 K001    A     None     var2         0        11
# 3 K001    B        2     var2         0        15
# 4 K002    B        1     var2         0        16
# 5 K008    B        2     var3     Pears  Bannanas
# 6 K009    A     None     var3    Apples  Bannanas
```

Comment: What is the motivation for this code? It looks obfuscated and therefore hard to review.

Comment: This code identifies discrepancies in two datasets and outputs a report identifying the discrepancies in each dataset. As indicated in the question, the `for` loop is what needs review. I would respectfully ask you to reconsider your downvote as it is quite straightforward and I closely considered the sites guidelines. The only thing that is not verbatim is the sample data as the real data is tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: what is the purpose of the map table? Roughly what needs to be done is pivot_longer df1 and df2, anti_join twice (each direction) and merge those results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention on how you create the map table, but from start with df1 and df2 to the end result I suggest to skip the whole for loop.

Efficient approach would be to:

1. convert df1 and df2 in long format
2. use anti_join to get the differences
3. merge the differences

**Code**

```
dfl1 <- df1 %>% mutate(var2 = as.factor(var2)) %>% # just make sure all are the same type
  pivot_longer(cols = 4:6, names_to = "variable", values_to = "entry")

dfl2 <- df2 %>% mutate(var2 = as.factor(var2)) %>% # just make sure all are the same type
  pivot_longer(cols = 4:6, names_to = "variable", values_to = "entry")

merge(anti_join(dfl1, dfl2), anti_join(dfl2, dfl1), by = c("id", "form", "instance", "variable"), suffixes = c("_df1", "_df2"))

#     id form instance variable entry_df1 entry_df2
# 1 K001    A     None     var2         0        11
# 2 K001    B        2     var2         0        15
# 3 K002    B        1     var2         0        16
# 4 K004    B        2     var1         I         A
# 5 K008    B        2     var3     Pears  Bannanas
# 6 K009    A     None     var3    Apples  Bannanas
```